# Deterministic serial communication using UART

Tags: ubuntu, serial

We are trying to receive sensitive data each 10 msec (100 bytes) via UART communication between Raspberry Pi 4 (runs ubuntu mate) and another embedded board that uses pic18. The UART is set as follows:

- Baud rate = 115200 bps
- 8-bit, no parity check

We are using the common code available in many internet resources that use the function"**ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)**;" to read the port after opening a file (serial interface) using the function "**int open(const char *pathname, int flags)**;"

To measure both, the number of data characters and the time for receiving such data we used clock_gettime.
We tried the following:

1. Running the receive function as a thread using pthread library and assigned it the highest priority
2. Using mutext to make the read function critical section

After checking the time spent on the console (using printf()), we found that the time for receiving correct data is not deterministic; sometimes it took 95 msec to receive the 100 characters, other 1 msec and in other cases, the measured time was (-ve)!!! which means the recorded time after receiving the data <  the start time of measurements !!!.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have mis-characterized the problem.  Instead of the UART (actually serial terminal), you need to pay more attention to how you try to measure time.  If you use the improper "clock" with **clock_gettime()**, then you can get negative differences when the "clock" is adjusted in order to stay synchronized with wall time.  Read the **man** page for **clock_gettime()**!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried using CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC and unfortunately both gives non deterministic and sometimes negative values

Comment: Without actual code and just vague descriptions, your issue is unsolvable.

Comment: Thank you very much
Excuse me for this out of scope question (As I am new member), but how to insert the code in this question. ?

Comment: You could use the [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1632197/edit) button under your post.  But your programming question might be more suitable at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), assuming that you provide a program that demonstrates the problem, e.g.  *"CLOCK_MONOTONIC ... gives ... sometimes negative values"*.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you very muc for your time